# SSH beanstalk from terminal using DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I am running an app in AWS Beanstalk, I use jenkins to do automatic deploys, manage crons, ecc, jenkins connects to the EC2 behind Beanstalk using the public ip.

The problem arises when the instance scales, since the IP of the EC2 will be different, I have to manually update Jenkins every time.

One of the simplest options would be to open the port 22 in the loadbalancer, but since I am using the recommended application loadbalancer, it only allows me to open the port 80/443. I was wondering if there is a way to create a dns record in route 53, that will automatically point to the right IP every time it scales?

I would like to avoid changing load balancer, because there are at least 20 environments that will need to be reconfigured.

I tried to look but no-one seems to have this issue, so either I have the wrong architecture, or it is too easy to fix.

Comment: "I use jenkins to do automatic deploys, manage crons, ecc, jenkins connects to the EC2 behind Beanstalk using the public ip." If you are using something other than Elastic Beanstalk to manage anything on the EC2 server, then all that will be reset if ElasticBeanstalk scales or otherwise replaces the instance. it sounds like you shouldn't be using ElasticBeanstalk at all, but a regular EC2 instance. Also, when a scale-up event happens, that means there will be more than one instance, so how do you plan to deal with multiple servers with multiple IPs?

Comment: I don't scale in multiple instances, because the business cannot be scaled horizontally. I use .extensions to have the instance the exact way.

Comment: If you're only ever using a single instance, you can assign an ElasticIP to keep the public IP from ever changing. It's really really strange that you are using both .ebextensions plus jenkins directly connecting to the server. Those are two different tools for doing the same thing, and I reiterate that it sounds like you should just be using EC2 instead of Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Jenkins will only listen for github hooks to deploy, and then I run some crons directly from jenkins to have more visibility, the rest is done through .extensions.
ok thanks I will have a look at ElasticIp. I use beanstalk, to save time on setting up supervisor, and all things related to deploying a python application.